# How to create a Paypoint.net Developer account?

Tags: payment-gateway

I am new to PayPoint.net and I am confused on how to create a PayPoint.net Developer Account?And also please suggest me PayPoint integration API Documentation.
Thank you.

Regards
Lokesh Koppaka

Answer (score 1):

By choosing one of the products at this link, you can click through to a developer guide including integration specification, code examples, and ability to setup a test developer account:

https://www.paypoint.com/en-gb/mobile-online/solutions/advanced-payments

For info, if you need a sophisticated HOSTED payment solution you should choose "Cashier". If you need a sophisticated API payment solution, you should choose "Cashier API". If you choose API but need help with PCI, you should also look at "CardLock".

If you want to get straight to the developer documentation, it is here:
https://developer.paypoint.com/

:) Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to quickly setup a developer account and have a play, go here:
https://developer.paypoint.com/payments/explore